# Intuitive illustration of n observation in each group of stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I would like to illustrate my number of observation I made in each group in a stacked percentage bar plot in a more intuitive way than just adding the numbers. I was thinking of dividing each "color" into n sections.

So for instance in the following, I would like to make lines or similar to split "feminine, female" into 16 sections, "masculine, male" into 60 etc.

```
df \<- dplyr::starwars
df_sum \<- na.omit( df %\>% count(gender, sex))

# gender    sex                n
# \<chr\>     \<chr\>          \<int\>
# 1 feminine  female            16
# 2 feminine  none               1
# 3 masculine hermaphroditic     1
# 4 masculine male              60
# 5 masculine none               5

ggplot(df_sum, aes(fill=sex, y=gender, x = n)) +
geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtwFt.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0vhO.png)

Other suggestions for an intuitive way of illustration the number of observations are also welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep using the original data you have stored in `df` you can add `color = "white"` to separate each observation.

```r
df %>%
  drop_na(gender) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = gender, x = 1, fill = sex)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity", color = "white")
```

[image: with separators]

Comment: Of course it could be that simple - thank you very much! :)